# Trigonometric identities with Winding lemma

Tags: trigonometry

using the fact, that for $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $sin(2k\pi X)=sin(2\pi X)$, how can we show, that
\begin{align}
\frac{cos^2(2\pi X)-sin^2(2\pi X)}{cos(2\pi X)sin(2\pi X)}=2\frac{sin(2\pi X)}{cos(2\pi X)}?
\end{align}

I have been trying forever, but keep running in circles

Comment: The equation isn't true for $X=1/8$.

Comment: use the double angle formula for both the top and bottom of the LHS, then use he winding lemma. Also, responding to @Micheal Hoppe, I presume this is only true when the functions are well defined.

Comment: For $X=1/8$ we get $0=2$ as $\sin(\pi/4)=\cos(\pi/4)$.

Comment: I second @MichaelHoppe in doubting that the alleged identity on the first line is correct.

Comment: And also the mention "fact" seems to be a factoid ...